# How to get values of dynamic Unchecked checkboxes in post PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form with other fields, I have a list of clients in a checkbox array. To get that list I use the database table-field and populate a list.
HTML FORM

```
<? if($this->clientCount > 0){?>
  <? foreach($this->client as $valuec) {?>
   <input type="checkbox" name="banner_allowed1[]" value="<?=$valuec['company_id']?>" <?if($valuec['banner_allowed']==1){echo 'checked="checked"';}?> style="margin:auto; size:20px;">&nbsp;<?=$valuec['title']?></label><br>
  <?}?>
<?}?>
```

Now when I submit the form, I need to know which one are unselected, because the form loads with the value selected from the database. I need to update the database table field value to zero(0) for the unselected ones.
I am finding a hard time with dynamic checkboxes to do a name value pair or get values of unselected checkboxes as post doesn't send unselected checkbox values

```
MY submit page in POST, only getting checked checkbox values
              if(!empty($_POST['banner_allowed1'])){
                foreach($_POST['banner_allowed1'] as $clientid1){     
                  $update['userid'] = $uid;
                  $update['banner_allowed'] = 1;
                  $this->db->update('clientlist', $update, "id=$clientid1");
                }
              } else {

       }
```

Comment: Simple in php page compare mysql and which have selected, then subtract and now you have new array with unselected value

Comment: Please show me how to subtract with the original array and posted array. new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i said in the comment you can use `array_diff` for select only the value isn't selected :

```
$dbarray = array('1','2','3','4');
$selectedarray = array('1','3');
$substract = array_diff($dbarray, $selectedarray);
print_r($substract); //print 2,4
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Simone. That was so simple. didn't thought about it.